# Permission GET_PROCESS_STATE_AND_OOM_SCORE

Tags: android

Looking in the android manifest I saw the permission `GET_PROCESS_STATE_AND_OOM_SCORE`. It's not granted to third-party apps but since I'm working on a system app I can use it, however I can't find where the permission is used. I mean the docs says: "Allows an application to query process states and current OOM adjustment scores." The question is how? I didn't find any API to perform this action.

Comment: I think [`ActivityManagerService.getProcessStatesAndOomScoresForPIDs`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#8078) is what you're looking for.